# merge Two data frames of different size in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:
df1:

```
Id   name Checksum
2001  A   e882
2002  B   2884
2002  C   ee12,ee84
2003  D   ee23
2004  E   ee42,ee43
2006  F   2884,2993,3884,3855
2006  G   344,122,288
```

I want output like this:

```
Id   name Checksum
2001  A   e882
2002  B   2884
2002  C   ee12
2002  C   ee84
2003  D   ee23
2004  E   ee42
2004  E   ee43
2006  F   2884
2006  F   2993
2006  F   3884
2006  F   3855
2006  G   344
2006  G   122
2006  G   288
```

I want to create new data frame like the above

How do I do it in python pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `list`s, then get [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for `length`.

Last create new `DataFrame` by `constructor` with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
s = df['Checksum'].str.split(',')
print (s)
0                      [e882]
1                      [2884]
2                [ee12, ee84]
3                      [ee23]
4                [ee42, ee43]
5    [2884, 2993, 3884, 3855]
6             [344, 122, 288]
Name: Checksum, dtype: object

l = s.str.len()
print (l)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    4
6    3
Name: Checksum, dtype: int64
```

---

```
cols = ['Id','name']
df = pd.DataFrame({x : np.repeat(df[x].values, l) for x in cols})
df['Checksum'] = np.concatenate(s)
df = df.reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)

      Id name Checksum
0   2001    A     e882
1   2002    B     2884
2   2002    C     ee12
3   2002    C     ee84
4   2003    D     ee23
5   2004    E     ee42
6   2004    E     ee43
7   2006    F     2884
8   2006    F     2993
9   2006    F     3884
10  2006    F     3855
11  2006    G      344
12  2006    G      122
13  2006    G      288
```

Altrnative with `chain.from_iterable`:

```
from  itertools import chain

s = df['Checksum'].str.split(',')
l = s.str.len()
cols = ['Id','name']
df = pd.DataFrame({x : np.repeat(df[x].values, l) for x in cols})
df['Checksum'] = list(chain.from_iterable(s))
df = df.reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
         Id name Checksum
0   2001    A     e882
1   2002    B     2884
2   2002    C     ee12
3   2002    C     ee84
4   2003    D     ee23
5   2004    E     ee42
6   2004    E     ee43
7   2006    F     2884
8   2006    F     2993
9   2006    F     3884
10  2006    F     3855
11  2006    G      344
12  2006    G      122
13  2006    G      288
```

Comment: @ jezrael It does not work and I have 15 columns like name columns, I can't do it manually ....I was just give example of name columns, I have similar columns like name columns

Comment: every thing is nan

Comment: I add more dynamic solution with outputs. Can you check it?

Comment: I got this error :  'str' object is not callable df['Checksum'] = list(chain.from_iterable(s))

Comment: If check my output of `s` your is similar?

Comment: Yes it is similar

Comment: and `df = pd.DataFrame({x : np.repeat(df[x].values, l) for x in cols})` works?

Comment: I got the answer

Comment: I have one idea - maybe some `NaN`s values. So try remove them as first step `df = df[df['Checksum'].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True)` and then my solution.

Comment: I got error on this line again : df['Checksum'] = list(chain.from_iterable(s))
str object is not callable , everything above this line is works perfectly fine .

Comment: If use `df['Checksum'] = np.concatenate(s)` instead `df['Checksum'] = list(chain.from_iterable(s))`  it works?

Comment: Hmmm, then I have no idea why second solution does not work. :( So use first one. thanks.